# Need some insights on solution / class design

Tags: class, design-patterns

Basically I want to have a class let say 'Job', roughly like this.

```
class Job {
    $jobId;
    $name;

    public function __construct($name) {
         $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function execute() {
        // excute some stuff here
    }

    public function setJobId() {
        $this->jobId = $this->generateId();
    }

    public function view() {
        return $this->name;
    }

    // Other stuffs
}
```

The requirements would be:

Client should be able instantiate this class and they can do $job = new Job() and do $job->view() to get the job name. However if the Client would like to execute it they need to set an ID. Note that the this ID should only be set once. Also, it's possible that Client simply wants to retrieve the job name and doesn't want execute it.

Insights? Perhaps I should not let the Client to instantiate the class just to be able to get its name?

Comment: What about the `generateId()` method? Is it expensive to call or something? And is there a possibility that a job is never executed and therefore doesn't need an id? Unless there is a reason not to do it, I think the line `$this->jobId = $this->generateId()` should be executed in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, it's possible the Client just want some information about the job but doesn't execute it. It's not expensive but it would seems redundant since we are not executing it anyway thus we won't need a unique job identifier to retrieve its execution result, etc. Yes putting the job id generation in the constructor would work but didn't feel like a good design.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider the following options:

1. Remove `setJobId()` and assign the job identifier in the constructor:

   ```
       ...
       public function __construct($name) {
           $this->name = $name;
           $this->jobId = $this->generateId();
       }
       ...
   ```
2. Remove `setJobId()` and assign the job identifier in the execution

   ```
       ...
       public function execute() {
           $this->jobId = $this->generateId();
           // execute some stuff here
       }
       ...
   ```
3. Make sure `setJobId()` does not reassign the id, although I might rename it to something more intuitive like `prepare()`:

   ```
       ...
       public function prepare() {
           if (is_null($this->jobId)) {  // or however nullity is checked on PHP
               $this->jobId = $this->generateId();
           } else {
               // do nothing or raise exception
               // because I've just found out that PHP has exceptions
           }
       }
       ...
   ```
4. If you don't do something like 1. or 2., you can check `jobId` within `execute()` and, if it has not been set, raise an error or call `setJobId()` - or his sexier new version `prepare()` ;^)